# How to connect to sql remote database from linux shared hosting

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, shared-hosting

I have an application developed in laravel that communicate with 2 databases, once is mysql it's in linux shared hosting. The another is sql and is in a remote server.

In localhost it's work well, I use `sqlsrv driver` to communicate with sql database but when I pass the project to shared hosting it can't connect with database, just with mysql database.

What I have to ask the hosting provider specifically?

This is my connections parameters:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8889'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'sql' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'remote_ip'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Comment: You probably don't have an sql server driver installed on the system.

Comment: 1443 is the default port! @Larnu

Comment: What error are you receiving? Are there any messages in the SQl Server's logs when you try to connect?

Comment: @Lanu - I believe it's tagged correctly; he's using both mysql and sql-server, but can't get the sql-server connection to work with his hosting provider.  It can be a networking config issue either on the linux shared host or the sql-server host, so it might be a better fit for another site.

Comment: I think I need freetds library no? @antlersoft

Answer (score 0):

First you should have the php_sql_server driver installed on the server (as php_extension).

for more info read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server and (the download files)  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

second, you should add the connection as a separate one in your env, like:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=null
DB_DATABASE=GRH
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=sfsd42563

DB_HOST2=remote_ip
DB_DATABASE2=db_name
DB_USERNAME2=username
DB_PASSWORD2=password
```

adn on your config/database.php  use as:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
'sqlsrv' => [
        'sqlsrv_Org' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port'     => null,//sqlsrv no port
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],
```